# Why am I getting an error using Compute Engine

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-compute-engine

I'm getting the following error when using Cloud Monitoring API v3 to query an Agent metric for disk space utilization:

404 Can not find metric resource_container_ids

I am passing in the correct project and vm instance. I can query just fine the Google Cloud metrics, but this Agent metric give me the error.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  The chart shows up fine online, but I need to get the data through my script.

```
results = client.list_time_series(
        request={
            "name": project_name,
            "filter": 'metric.type = "agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used" AND metric.labels.instance_name = "MY_INSTANCE"',
            "interval": interval,
            "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
        }
     )
```

Ok, I discovered that passing in the instance name (vm) is not correct.  After removing it, data came back fine, but I only want data to come back for a certain vm.  But the metric won't allow passing in a vm name.  Any ideas how to restrict the data to just that vm?

Comment: can you show your query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a laptop with me to test right now, but I think that you need to use the instance id (resource.instance_id)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason metrics did not work for me as well, but using **resources** did e.g `f'metric.type = "agent.googleapis.com/memory/percent_used" AND resource.labels.instance_id = "{instance_id}"`